# Display a responsive image and label in a table for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm new to iOS I'm not 100% sure how constraints works yet.

I have a table with 3 profiles.

[image]

As you can see Andrew show as `an...`

This is my current constraint settings

[image]

How do I display the name in **full** ?

Comment: The name label shouldn't have a width constraint, at most it should be constrained to the trailing margin of the cell

Comment: Is there a way to update the constraint?

Comment: Select the width constraint in the storyboard and delete it.  You may also need to provide a horizontal and vertical constraint, such as the horizontal spacing between the profile image and the label and centre vertically with the image, as an example.  You goal should be to try and provide constraints that reach from one edge of the container to the other, when used with table cells

Comment: let me try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UILabel` has the capabilities to calculate it's own height and width, so you don't tend to want to constrain it, instead, you can define the bounds of its sizable area, so it doesn't expand beyond the bounds of the viewable area (optionally)

[image: Layout]

When laying out `UITableViewCell`s with auto layout, you intention is to provide constraints that reach from the top of the cell to the bottom. This provides the auto layout with the ability to dynamically size the cell based on it's content.

In this example, I've constrained the `UIImageView` to the top and bottom margins (with a constant of `0`), but, I've also constrained the width of the `UIImageView` to `50` and added an aspect ratio of `1:1`.  This has the effect of making the cell 66 points high, as the auto layout won't try and resize the image, but instead, will resize the cell to match.

The image view's leading edge is also constraint to the leading margin

The label has is vertically centred to the image view and has a horizontal spacing constraint of `8`.  Optionally, you can also constrain the trailing edge of the label to the trailing margin.  If you also set the `UILabel`'s `lines` properties to `0`, this will provide a level of automatic line wrapping.

This basically defines the x/y position of both the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` and in the case of the `UIImageView` it's width and height as well, allowing auto layout the ability to calculate the size of the cell (at least in this case, the desired height - assuming you've set the `UITableView` up to use `estimatedRowHeight`s)

You might find [Self-sizing Table View Cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) and interesting read

*nb: This is just one way to accomplish the result and assumes the label will never be higher then the `UIImageView`

Answer (score 1):

To display it in full remove any width constraint you gave to it , as it's content is by default intrinsic , to make it wrap if it's width will exceed screen width

```
img - 10 - lbl - 10   // set .lines =  0 && remove height constraint
```

Comment: How do I do that ? via the code ? or Interface Builder ?

Comment: interface builder

Comment: @kyo if you set aspect ratio constraint you should remove it also